# Why I get "Android package name conflict" error while installing apks with different package names?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk, signed-apk

I created two years ago an android app called "Belgian Beer" with com.nauwstudio.belgian_beer as id.
I always get trouble to get this app visible on Google Play Store and I never understand why. 
So I decided to create a new app from the same updated source code. I wish to call it "bbeer" with id be.nauwstudio.bbeer. 
To do so, I updated in Android Studio the app id and the package name but when I try to put the two apps into my phone, I get an "Package Name conflict error". I signed them with two different keystore and I don't get any error message bout signign but only about naming.

Is that someone knows on which settings are verified when by apk installer to say that there is app package name conflict ?

Thanks a lot,

Pierre

Comment: Did you edit package name in app-level `build.gradle` file and `AndroidManifest.xml` file, too? Delete bin folder and refresh build again.

Comment: Yes I updated it in the two files. Unfortunately, I don't see any "bin" folder in my Android Studio project browser.